# If $f,g$ are two endomorphisms of $E$ such that $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$ and $g$ is nilpotent show that: $f$ is invertible => $f+g$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If $f,g$ are two endomorphisms of E such that $ f(g(x))= g(f(x))$ and $g(x)$ is nilpotent show that:

A) If $f(x)$ is invertible then $f+g$ is invertible too.

B) If $f(x)+g(x)$ is invertible then $f(x)$ is invertible too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, if $\;g^n=0\;$ , then do the following trick

$$\frac1{f+g}=\frac1f\;\frac1{1+f^{-1}g}=\frac1f\left(1-f^{-1}g+f^{-2}g^2-\ldots\right)$$

Now, the above sums *ends* at $\;f^{-n}g^n=0\;$ ...so there you have the inverse we want:

$$(f+g)^{-1}=f^{-1}\left(I-f^{-1}g+f^{-2}g^2-\ldots\pm f^{-(n-1)}g^{n-1}\right)$$

with $\;I:=$ the identity endomorphism.

Comment: This definitely solves A) by giving (f+g)^-1 in terms of the inverse of f but we would still need f^-1 in terms of the inverse of f+g for part B

Comment: @GeoffNaylor Using a similar formula, $\frac{1}{(f+g)(Id-(f+g)^{-1}g)}=\frac{1}{f+g} (1+(f+g)^{-1}g+(f+g)^{-2}g^2+...)$. I hope i didn't miss anything? By the way, thank you DonAntonio, i just think we should mention that if $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$ then $f^{-1}(g(x)) = g(f^{-1}(x))$ in order to make everything clear.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Since $f$ and $g$ commute then they are co-trigonalizable over $\Bbb C$ in the same basis and since $f$ is invertible then its eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ are different of zero and since $g$ is nilpotent then its eigenvalues are $0$. What are the eigenvalues of $f+g$? Can you take it from here?

Comment: I don't think we can assume E is a vector space that can be embedded in C can we?

Answer (score 2):

Just a remark: the whole stuff has nothing to do with linear algebra, but is pure ring theory. Take for example the first part: let $R$ be a ring with $1$ and let $g$ be  nilpotent element of $R$. If $g^e=0$ one always has:

$
(1-g)(1+g+g^2+\ldots +g^{e-1})=(1+g+g^2+\ldots +g^{e-1})(1-g)=1
$

thus $1-g$ is invertible in $R$.

If $g$ is nilpotent, the same holds for $-g$, so that $1+g$ is invertible as well.

If $hg=gh$, then $hg$ is nilpotent too, so that $1+hg$ is invertible.

If $f$ is invertible and $fg=gf$, then $f^{-1}g=gf^{-1}$, so that $1+f^{-1}g$ is invertible.

The product of invertible elements is invertible, so that $f(1+f^{-1}g)=f+g$ is invertible.

H